# In antlr4 generated function for a rule how to count how many times a sub-rule function is called in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, antlr, antlr4, language-translation

I am working on language translation through antlr4. Almost everything is going good but the problem i have now is that in atlr4 generated function for a rule i have to count how many times a sub-rule function is called in JavaScript. It is working fine if you do it for a token inside a function generated for a rule. 
Example:

```
Listener.prototype.exitRequire = function (ctx) 
{
var itemlength= ctx.ID().length;
}
```

For the Rule: " require: REQUIRE ID AS STRINGLITERAL REQUIRE ".

But when there is another sub-rule inside the that rule then i can't get the count of the sub-function.
Example:

For the Rule: "order: ORDER NEWLINE+ (orderItem NEWLINE+)+ END ORDER NEWLINE+"
as there is a sub-rule 'orderitem' and it can be repeated so i want to have a count or length of it that how many times it is executed.

i tried it like this but not working.

```
Listener.prototype.exitOrder = function (ctx)
 {   
var length= ctx.orderitem().length;
}
```

Can you please give me a way to achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: Trying to understand your question: are you asking how many times a subrule matched in a given rule? Have you looked at the generated parse tree?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Actually i am translating one language input to another language. I have almost converted it but now i am having a problem in looping. Actually i want a counter that have the value that how many times a sub-rule function is called. So it will be easy then for me to use a loop till the counter and produce my outputs for the sub-rule according to that.